# how to pass an argument to angularjs custom filter

Tags: angularjs

i want to be able to pass different price point to the filter but the way it defined right now it not working unless i hard code it in eg priceArray.push(value.price)

```js
var priceSumUp = function ($log){

    return function(arrayObj, nameValue){
      
       var priceArray = [],
           totalPrice = 0;
       function sumUp(first, second){return first + second}

       ng.forEach(arrayObj, function(value, key, obj){      
           priceArray.push(value.price);
       });

       totalPrice = priceArray.reduce(sumUp, 0);
       //console.log(priceArray);
       return totalPrice;
    };
}
```

```html
<div class="" ng-bind-html="vm.getisSelected | priceSumUp:price"></div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want to do. Include a sample of the value of `vm.getisSelected` and what you want the result of your filter to be.

Comment: Also, the question doesn't make sense. You have the array being passed in: `arrayObj` and the additional argument `nameValue` as parameters, but you aren't using them. You clearly know how to pass them in, you're doing it!

Comment: m59 my bed it was suppose to be priceArray.push(value.nameValue) but the answer given work for me, thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this...

First make sure you are passing the right argument. Either change it to

```
$scope.price = 'price'
// or
<div ng-bind="items | priceSumUp:'price'"></div>
```

Next you can use the array-like ECMA object properties to access the item...

```
return function(arrayObj, v){
   var priceArray = arrayObj.map(function(obj){
     return obj[v]
   })
   ...
}
```

See my [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vr0aotg4QuALC6byGgeL?p=preview) this would also allow for say...

```
<div ng-bind="items | priceSumUp:'tax'"></div>
```